# How to stop notifications to fans as an facebook page admin

Tags: facebook

I want to make a small changes in about section of facebook page. But I don't want to fans receive annoying notify during editing. Is there any way to stop notification to fans as a facebook page admin.
Thanks,

Comment: Are you referring to iOS push notifications or actual Facebook notifications?

Comment: Facebook notifications

Comment: seems like a question for Facebook support, as it isn't really related to programming. I'd guess that there isn't a way to do that though.